# iOS 8. Drag and drop animation similar to pages in Safari on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, drag-and-drop, icarousel

Here is an approximate view for iOS 8 on iPad.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQKuD.jpg

As I understand, the only way to simulate these columns is to use a lot of `iCarousel` instances. But there some problems with dragging which may involve from a view from one carousel instance up to some carousel instances at once.

Could you describe a list of actions I need to perform for such dragging animation? Even if it will be without of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've understood that if I use `iCarousel` then I must implement drag and drop fully manually. So I take `HMLauncherView` which vice versa has somehow implemented drag and drop but by default supports only grid of views. So now I try to add to it some functionality which is similar to `iCarousel`